# Qbasic GOTO to a line with Apostophe

Tags: goto, apostrophe, qbasic

I'm trying to "convert" an old program in QBasic to Java.
I have a problem while debugging and I think is related to this GOTO statement.
I know that a line with an apostrophe is ignored but in this case the statement GOTO targets that line. Is ignored the first time and after with the GOTO statement is not?And the apostrophe concerns only the variable R12 and X12 or also R22,X22?

This is the .BAS file :)

```
*

    4010 'R12 = R2MA + ((R2A * R2M * (R2A + R2M) + S ^ 2 * (R2A * X2M ^ 2 + R2M * X2A ^ 2)) / ((R2A + R2M) ^ 2 + S ^ 2 * (X2A + X2M) ^ 2))
    4014 'X12 = X2D + ((R2A ^ 2 * X2M + R2M ^ 2 * X2A + S ^ 2 * X2A * X2M * (X2A + X2M)) / ((R2A + R2M) ^ 2 + S ^ 2 * (X2A + X2M) ^ 2))
         R22 = ((R2A * XMMU ^ 2 + R2M * XAVVMU ^ 2) * S ^ 2 + R2A * R2M * RT2) / (RT2 ^ 2 + S ^ 2 * XT2 ^ 2)
         X22 = (X2A * (R2M ^ 2 + S ^ 2 * X2M ^ 2) + X2M * (R2A ^ 2 + S ^ 2 * X2A ^ 2) + 2 * X2AVM * (R2A * R2M - S ^ 2 * X2AVM * XT2)) / (RT2 ^ 2 + S ^ 2 * XT2 ^ 2)
         X22 = X22 + X2D
         R22 = R22 / ZUN: X22 = X22 / ZUN
    4016 A1 = R22 * E1 ^ 2 / (P2 * X22 ^ 2 + R22 * E1 ^ 2)
    4020 S = .5 * A1 - SQR(A1 * (.25 * A1 - R22 * P2 / E1 ^ 2))
    4030 G1 = (PFE / (3 * (VF * (FR / 100)) ^ 2)) * ZUN
    4040 A2 = (R22 / S) ^ 2 + X22 ^ 2: B2 = R22 / (S * A2): C2 = X22 / A2: D2 = B2 + G1
    4050 E2 = C2 + B1: F2 = D2 ^ 2 + E2 ^ 2: G2 = D2 / F2: H2 = E2 / F2: Z2 = SQR(G2 ^ 2 + H2 ^ 2)
    4060 I2 = G2 + R11: L = H2 + X11: ZTOT = SQR(I2 ^ 2 + L ^ 2)
    4070 I1 = 1 / ZTOT
    4080 E3 = I1 * Z2
    4090 IF ABS(E1 - E3) > P0 THEN 5800
.
.
.

    5800 E1 = (E1 + E3) / 2
    5810 GOTO 4010



*
```

Comment: The statement following the line number is ignored, the line number exists so the jump is equivalent to GOTO <the next line number>

Comment: Line 4014 is ignored? I mean X12,R22,X22, are ignored or only X12?

Answer (score 3):

This sure is an odd way to write a QBasic program, usually you either number all of the lines or none of them. You can run a small test program to see how QB handles GOTO in this case. So something like this:

```
10 I = 0
20 'PRINT "Test line 20"
30 'PRINT "Test line 30
    PRINT "Test line 40"
    PRINT "Test line 50"
60 PRINT "Test line 60"
70 I = I + 1
80 IF (I <= 1) GOTO 20
90 PRINT "THE END"
```

I tried this in QB4.5 and the output is this:

```
Test line 40
Test line 50
Test line 60
Test line 40
Test line 50
Test line 60
THE END
```

The GOTO statement works as normal but the contents of lines 20 and 30 are not executed, it is treated as comment. So to answer your question, in your case the lines with `R12 = ..` and `X12 = ..` will be ignored and not executed, and the lines with `R22 = ..` and `X22 = ..` etc. are processed as normal.

Comment: It isn't weird at all... If this started of as an old program it may have been in a BASIC environment that required line numbers then later moved to not require line numbers.  The old line numbers were just never removed.